# insert in other table from other table with a fix value

Tags: sql

I want to insert records in a table with one fix value and all values coming from string split function.

Output of `string[dbo].[StringSplit](@SelectedTables,',')`:

```
4

5

6

7
```

Value of `@newid` is **101**

Now I want to insert in table like:

```
101 4

101 5

101 6

101 7
```

This is my query:

```
insert into tblC6FD_QueryBuilderTableAssoc(QueryBuilderID,TableID)
select @NewId ,(select String from  [dbo].[StringSplit](@SelectedTables,','))
```

What is problem in above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT @NewId ,
       String 
FROM   [dbo].[StringSplit](@SelectedTables,',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
insert into tblC6FD_QueryBuilderTableAssoc(QueryBuilderID,TableID)
select @NewId, String 
from  [dbo].[StringSplit](@SelectedTables,',')
```